# APNS connection closed after sending notification

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ioexception

I'm working on an APNS provider build on .Net, and I'm using an SSLStream to communicate with APNS. I'm facing a minor issue that is really annoying me.

Sometimes, When I send a notification, and after that the stream writer flushes the notification bytes, the stream reader raises the following exception without any reason.

```
IOException System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport 
connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly 
closed by the remote host
```

According the Apple's documentation, an error message should be received prior to closing the connection in case of errors, but I'm not getting any messages.

Anyone has a clue about this case? why is the connection closed right after the "Push"? Is it a known problem?